# Why am I seeing an empty artefact for an ASP.Net (PREVIEW) build?

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a legacy web application that I've recently migrated to VSTS (from an old TFS2008 server), and am now trying to set up CI/CD in VSTS.

I've got an on-premise build agent, which claims to successfully built the solution, (i.e. the build passes) but the artefact generated comes out as an empty "drop" folder, which I don't understand.

As this is an on-premise build server, I have the luxury of being able to poke its file system, and I can see that `<agent root>\_work\20\a` is indeed empty, even though the associated website has built, and has even precompiled (i.e. the thing to be deployed does exist at `<agent root>\_work\20\s\PrecompiledWeb`) So what am I missing to connect the two proverbial dots, over and above what the "ASP.NET (PREVIEW)" build template gave me to start with?

The solution file is pretty straight forward:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.27004.2009
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "HorizonDashboard", "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard", "{0D9EC6BB-C1A9-4A12-BAA0-61B7205307E6}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv3.5"
        ProjectReferences = "{3F6ED2DF-3AAC-40E5-8DFF-101EBD2BCA77}|MscTools.dll;{83226B78-CB43-4BCC-BEFA-B3CCB4E387CB}|MscCommon.dll;{F4A2CB09-7ED0-40AC-810A-489FEB7A3D45}|MscUk.Printing.dll;"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/HorizonDashboard"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\HorizonDashboard\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/HorizonDashboard"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\HorizonDashboard\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "5343"
        SlnRelativePath = "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "MyCompany.Tools", "Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\MyCompany.Tools.vbproj", "{3F6ED2DF-3AAC-40E5-8DFF-101EBD2BCA77}"
EndProject
...
```

The (slightly edited down to fit here) build log looks all fairly sensible, as the web project hasn't really been tinkered with for several years:

```
2017-11-22T12:37:25.5742010Z ##[section]Starting: Phase 1
2017-11-22T12:37:25.5771997Z Current agent version: '2.124.0'
2017-11-22T12:37:26.7802445Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize Job
2017-11-22T12:37:26.7922437Z Prepare build directory.
2017-11-22T12:37:26.8532483Z Set build variables.
2017-11-22T12:37:26.8592461Z Download all required tasks.
2017-11-22T12:37:26.9112479Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
2017-11-22T12:37:26.9532524Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2017-11-22T12:37:27.0302567Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
2017-11-22T12:37:27.0312583Z Setting environment variable TFVC_BUILDAGENT_POLICYPATH
2017-11-22T12:37:27.0322584Z Querying workspace information.
2017-11-22T12:37:29.3233381Z ##[command]tf vc get /version:68375 /recursive /overwrite C:\agent\_work\20\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2017-11-22T12:37:30.3883833Z C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Test\MyCompany.CommonTests:
2017-11-22T12:37:30.3904477Z Replacing MyCompany.CommonTests.vbproj
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4043870Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4043870Z C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Test\MyCompany.Tools.Test:
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4043870Z Replacing MyCompany.Tools.Test.vbproj
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4053852Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4053852Z C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Test\MyCompany.Printing.Test:
2017-11-22T12:37:30.4053852Z Replacing MyCompany.Printing.Test.vbproj
2017-11-22T12:37:31.0074074Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3047646Z ##[section]Starting: Build solution
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z Task         : Visual Studio Build
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z Version      : 1.125.0
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613727)
2017-11-22T12:37:40.3057684Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-22T12:37:42.2128393Z ##[command]"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.125.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [15.0,16.0) -latest -format json
2017-11-22T12:37:42.7308577Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.125.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=317b7114-2199-4657-88e7-322c162344f7|SolutionDir=C:\agent\_work\20\s"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.125.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="C:\agent\_work\20\a\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_f214a5e7-a852-44ab-a368-c1d8cf3736ca_build_282_29739"
2017-11-22T12:37:42.8568940Z Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
2017-11-22T12:37:42.8978900Z Build started 22/11/2017 12:37:42.
2017-11-22T12:37:43.0938699Z Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.0958797Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.0958797Z   Building solution configuration "release|any cpu".
2017-11-22T12:37:43.4928823Z Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" (1) is building "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.4928823Z Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (2) is building "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\MyCompany.Tools.vbproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5089198Z CoreCompile:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5089198Z Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5149173Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5149173Z   Touching "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\obj\Release\MyCompany.Tools.vbproj.CopyComplete".
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5178950Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5178950Z   MyCompany.Tools -> C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.dll
2017-11-22T12:37:43.5299775Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\MyCompany.Tools.vbproj" (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6828940Z Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (2) is building "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.vbproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6828940Z Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.vbproj" (4) is building "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\MyCompany.Printing.csproj" (5:2) on node 1 (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6828940Z CoreCompile:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6828940Z Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6859251Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6859251Z   MyCompany.Printing -> C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.dll
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6868979Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb" to "bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb".
2017-11-22T12:37:43.6928941Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\MyCompany.Printing.csproj" (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:44.0679081Z CoreResGen:
2017-11-22T12:37:44.0679081Z   No resources are out of date with respect to their source files. Skipping resource generation.
2017-11-22T12:37:44.1679144Z CoreCompile:
2017-11-22T12:37:44.1689119Z   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\vbc.exe /noconfig /baseaddress:11000000 /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Data,System.Diagnostics,System.Linq /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict+ /nowarn:42016,42017,42018,42019,42032,42353,42354,42355 /nostdlib /removeintchecks- /rootnamespace:MyCompany /sdkpath:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 /highentropyva- /doc:obj\Release\MyCompany.Common.xml /define:"CONFIG=\"Release\",TRACE=-1,_MyType=\"Windows\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /reference:"C:\agent\_work\20\s\3rdParty\Microsoft Office 2003\Main\Lib\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll","C:\agent\_work\20\s\3rdParty\SQL Server\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll",C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.dll,C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.dll,C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\Office.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll",C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll",C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.Linq.dll",C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.DirectoryServices.dll,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Web.Extensions.dll",C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /main:"MyCompany.(None)" /debug- /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\MyCompany.Common.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /resource:obj\Release\MyCompany.Locations.CustomerSites.resources /resource:Resources\MyCompany.Logo.emf,MyCompany.MyCompany.Logo.emf /target:library /warnaserror+ /utf8output Accounting\AccountingWeek.vb Accounting\Characteristics.vb Accounting\Currencies.vb Accounting\Currency.vb Accounting\ExchangeRate.vb Accounting\ExchangeRateHelper.vb Testing\PropertyChangeMonitor.vb Testing\XmlValidator.vb UserActionLog.vb ValidationError.vb XmlSqlHelper.vb
2017-11-22T12:37:44.1909458Z   Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4009983Z   
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4189983Z _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4189983Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb" to "bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4209998Z   Touching "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\obj\Release\MyCompany.Common.vbproj.CopyComplete".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4250044Z CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4250044Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\MyCompany.Common.dll" to "bin\Release\MyCompany.Common.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4290072Z   MyCompany.Common -> C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Common.dll
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4290072Z   Copying file from "obj\Release\MyCompany.Common.xml" to "bin\Release\MyCompany.Common.xml".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.4389949Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.vbproj" (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5420560Z Build:
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5420560Z   No way to resolve conflict between "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" and "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91". Choosing "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" arbitrarily.
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5420560Z   Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" from Version "11.0.0.0" [C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll] to Version "12.0.0.0" [C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5640054Z ##[warning]C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj(0,0): Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: 
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5640054Z C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: 
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5650049Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Tools.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5650049Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5660117Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.xml" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Tools.xml".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5670163Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\de\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5690107Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\es\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\es\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5700350Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\fr\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\fr\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5721059Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\it\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\it\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5740121Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\ja\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ja\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5751155Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\ko\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ko\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5770606Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\pt\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\pt\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5780522Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\ru\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ru\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5820109Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\zh-CHS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\zh-CHS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5840323Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Tools\bin\Release\zh-CHT\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\zh-CHT\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5850331Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Common.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Common.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5860191Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5960087Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.5990172Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Tools.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6000155Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Printing.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6000155Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\office.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\office.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6020134Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6060085Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\stdole.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\stdole.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6060085Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Common.xml" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Common.xml".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6100118Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Tools.xml" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Tools.xml".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6110157Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Printing.pdb".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6120076Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\de\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\de\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6130172Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\es\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\es\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6150139Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\fr\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\fr\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6170152Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\it\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\it\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6180147Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\ja\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ja\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6190140Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\ko\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ko\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6210157Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\pt\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\pt\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6230079Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\ru\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\ru\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6240117Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\zh-CHS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\zh-CHS\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6260022Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\MasterReference\Code\MyCompany.Common\bin\Release\zh-CHT\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\zh-CHT\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6280124Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.dll" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Printing.dll".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6290117Z   Copying file from "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Utility\Code\MyCompany.Printing\bin\Release\MyCompany.Printing.pdb" to "Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\\Bin\MyCompany.Printing.pdb".
2017-11-22T12:37:46.6370118Z   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /HorizonDashboard -p Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\HorizonDashboard\ 
2017-11-22T12:37:51.6752006Z ##[warning]Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\TreeViewReports.aspx.vb(138,0): Warning BC42324: Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable.
2017-11-22T12:37:51.6752006Z C:\agent\_work\20\s\Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\TreeViewReports.aspx.vb(138): warning BC42324: Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable. [C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj]
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1572182Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1602167Z Done Building Project "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" (default targets).
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1702198Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1702198Z Build succeeded.
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1712201Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1752157Z "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1782189Z "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1792194Z (Build target) -> 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1792194Z   C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj : warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1802191Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1802191Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z "C:\agent\_work\20\s\Horizon.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z "C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z   C:\agent\_work\20\s\Source\Code\HorizonDashboard\TreeViewReports.aspx.vb(138): warning BC42324: Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable. [C:\agent\_work\20\s\HorizonDashboard.metaproj]
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z     2 Warning(s)
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z     0 Error(s)
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z 
2017-11-22T12:37:52.1812189Z Time Elapsed 00:00:09.27
2017-11-22T12:37:52.2242207Z ##[section]Finishing: Build solution
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Artifact
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z Description  : Publish build artifacts to Visual Studio Team Services/TFS or a file share
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z Version      : 1.124.1
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
2017-11-22T12:38:01.4345754Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3426112Z ##[command]robocopy.exe /E /COPY:DA /NP /R:3 "C:\agent\_work\20\a" "\\tfs-build\Builds\Live\Horizon Dashboard_20171122.1\drop" *
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3426112Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3426112Z -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3426112Z    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z   Started : 22 November 2017 12:38:02
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z    Source : C:\agent\_work\20\a\
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z      Dest : \\tfs-build\Builds\Live\Horizon Dashboard_20171122.1\drop\
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z     Files : *
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z        
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z   Options : /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /NP /R:3 /W:30 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z                       0    C:\agent\_work\20\a\
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3436082Z     Dirs :         1         0         0         0         0         0
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3487067Z    Files :         0         0         0         0         0         0
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3496344Z    Bytes :         0         0         0         0         0         0
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3496344Z    Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3496344Z    Ended : 22 November 2017 12:38:02
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3496344Z 
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3496344Z ##[debug]robocopy exit code '0'
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3916122Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Associate Artifact
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3916122Z Associated artifact 26828 with build 29739
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3916122Z ##[section]Async Command End: Associate Artifact
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3916122Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Artifact
2017-11-22T12:38:02.3936125Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
2017-11-22T12:38:02.4046142Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
2017-11-22T12:38:02.4106128Z ##[section]Finishing: Phase 1
```

Comment: You did a build, but did you do a publish? What was the output path set for the publish? We pass the argument `--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Comment: @mason the path to publish is the default, i.e "`$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`", but the reult of the build doesn't seem to be ending up in there?

Comment: When you say publish, are you saying you have a Publish Build Artifact step? Or is it a Publish .NET Core Preview step?

Comment: @mason this is the "Publish Artefact" step that is part of the "ASP.NET (PREVIEW)" build template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Web Site" project is different with "Web App" project. The "Asp.Net (PREVIEW)" template is used for Web Application Project.

For "Web Site" project, you just need to deploy the project source folder to your server directly. So you just need to set the "Path to Publish" to "`Build.SourcesDirectory`" in "Publish Artifact" step.

Comment: So you're saying the ASP.Net release template is the wrong one to use?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes.

Comment: Is there a template that does work with ASP.Net projects then?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No, but you just need to change the path to publish as I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Build artifacts are located in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` by default, so you should specify the output directory in MSBuild arguments or add a Copy files tasks to copy the artifacts from `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`. Detail options as below:

#### Option 1: set MSBuild Arguments

You can set the MSbuild Arguments as:

```
/p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Or as:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
```

#### Option 2: use Copy Files task

Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Contents: user wildcards to specify which files need to copy

Target Folder: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Comment: so I'm already using option 1(b), i.e. my arguments to MSBuild are "`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`" (per the default for the build template)

Comment: I've added a slimmed down copy of the build log above

Comment: Is your project Web application for VB? And Can you share the project in one drive?

Comment: This is a (VB) "Web Site" project, as opposed to a "Web application" project, but I've added the relevant portion of the solution to the question

Answer (score -1):

In the MS Build Arguments on the Visual Studio Build step, I pass these arguments:

```
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
/p:DeployOnbuild=True
/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true
/p:GenerateBuildInfoConfigFile=false
/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```

The build results end up in the `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)`. From there I either do a Copy and Publish Build Artifacts step (deprecated) or a Copy task and a Publish Build Artifacts task. Either way, it ends up copying the results from the `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\ApplicationName\_PublishedWebsites\ApplicationName` folder to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\ApplicationName` folder and publishing that.